GelatoRelaySDK/sponsoredCall: Failed with error: Too many requests, please try again later
I  implemented Gelato Relay sdk  in my app, and I am  constantly getting this error, how can I solve this?

Gelato has its own API limits (as stated in its terms of service: https://www.gelato.com/legal/api-terms). Without additional information it will be difficult for us to provide an answer; could you please edit your question to provide more details about your implementation? For example if you are using one of Safe{Core} SDK kits, and how. Thank you in advance

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
